# Why doesn't Firefox obey my icon theme?

Tags: 10.04, firefox, icons, faenza

I'm using the Faenza icon set in 10.04LTS. Within the gnome-panel, alt-tab and possible more instances Firefox does not use the Faenza icons. All other apps seem too, just not Firefox.

Any idea why, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct fix, but it might still be acceptable:

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/gtk-native/

A Firefox theme which applies your gtk theme. <strike>I *think* that</strike> it changes the icons too

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the Faenza icons ? When I installed them from this ppa it works :

https://launchpad.net/~tiheum/+archive/equinox

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

Comment: That is the same way I have them installed. The machine in question is 10.04 LTS. The main thing that bothers me is the non-Faenza icon in the gnome-panel window list.